# HTML form encoding in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, url, qurl

It seems that QUrl does not support HTML form encoding/decoding of urls (encoding spaces as a plus sign, etc.). Does this functionality reside somewhere else in Qt, or do I need to find another library for it? In the latter case, what do you suggest?

Comment: Do you look for [QUrl::fromPercentEncoding](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qurl.html#fromPercentEncoding)/[QUrl::toPercentEncoding](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qurl.html#toPercentEncoding)? I know spaces are encoded to `%20`.

Comment: Well, that's the problem. I want them to be encoded as +.